# Calculate probability of alarm and the posterior probability of this alarm being false over different frequencies of output

Tags: bayesian, posterior, signal-detection, false-positive-rate, true-positive-rate

I have the following information for an automatic detection system that output a warning when a signal is detected:

- Specificity: .99 (i.e. a false positive rate $FP = .01$)
- Sensitivity: .9 (i.e. a true positive rate $TP = .9$)
- Probability that the signal to be detected is present: .1 *per hour* (i.e. a $p(S) = .1$)

I would like to calculate the probability of:

- A warning (regardless of the presence of the signal)
- The posterior probability of having no signal in the presence of a warning

Note that I would like to calculate the above parameters over several output frequencies (e.g. one every hour, one every thirty minutes, etc.)

To do so I have thought to use the following formulas, as suggested for example [here](https://thestatsninja.com/2019/03/03/how-to-decipher-false-positives-and-negatives-with-bayes-theorem/):

$p(alarm) = (FP * (1 - p(S))) + (TP * p(S))$

$p(nosignal\rvert alarm) =  \dfrac{(FP * (1 - p(S)))}{p(alarm)}$

If I plug the parameters specified above in these formulas, I got an overall probability of alarm of `~.11` with an associated probability that the signal is not present even if the alarm is given of `~.08`. I interpret these estimate as probability *per hour* if my system only gives one prediction *per hour*.

The problems start for me when I want to calculate the same probabilities, but when my system has an higher output frequency.

I reasoned that, if we assume that the probability per hour is uniformly distributed (i.e. if any 'moment' within an hour has the same probability of being the moment where the signal is present), then I can convert the probability per hour that I started with to other time scales simply by dividing it. For example, the probability of observing the signal within 10 minutes will be `.1/6`. However, I am not sure that, even if my assumption is true, this is the correct way of converting the prior.

Assuming that the way in which I convert the prior holds, then I can recalculate my probabilities of interest simply plugging in the newly calculated $p(S)$

For an output frequency of 1 per 10 minutes, I have a probability of alarm of `~.03` with a probability of having no signal when an alarm is given of `~.4`. This make intuitive sense to me: as the prior goes down, the probability of an alarm goes also down, but the probability that the signal is not present even if the alarm is given goes up. However, I have some problem with the interpretation at this point:

- am I right in interpreting this probability as *per 10 minutes* ?
- if I wanted to go back to the *per hour* scale (i.e. what are the probabilities of an alarm, and what are the probability that the signal is not present when the alarm is given *per hour* with a system that has 6 outputs per hour) should I multiply back the probability of the alarm by 6 ? And what about the posterior probability of the signal not being there when an alarm is given ?

Comment: What is the nature of the signal? Is it an instantaneous event with a constant rate of occurrence? If that is the case, it may occur more than once during any specified time frame (the number of occurrences between detector outputs will be Poisson-distributed). When looking at different reporting frequencies for the detector, it would be easier to use units of *per occurrence* rather than per hour for sensitivity.

Comment: The signal is not instantaneous and I think that a constant rate of occurrence may not be a safe assumption. As for the units, reporting to *hour of use* is the standard in the field I am working in, and as such it would be preferable to stick to it.